# MediaQuery not working.For the desktop(more than 992px) all left in one row,for tablet first 2 should be 50% width and 3rd 100% ,for mobile all 100%

Tags: html, css, media-queries

MediaQuery is not working. For the desktop (more than 992px) all left in one row, for tablet first 2 should be 50% width and 3rd 100%, for mobile all 100%.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  float: left;
}

h1 {
  text-align: "center";
  font-family: cursive;
}

.div1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.div1h1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #f2a4a2;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 191px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
}

.div2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.div2h2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #8f201e;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 191px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
}

.div3 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.div3h3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #f5f187;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 191px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}


/*media queriues--------------------------------------------------*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  /* for desktop */
  div div {
    float: left;
    margin: auto;
    width: 20%;
  }
}

@media(min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px) {
  /* for tablet */
  div div {
    margin: auto;
  }
  .div1,
  .div2 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .div3 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
  /* for mobile */
  div div {
    /* one top of another */
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
  <h1 style="text-align : center"> our menu</h1>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width , initial-scale = 1 ">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="div1">
      <h3 class="div1h1"> chicken </h3>
      <p class="div1para1">
        Borders and Colors: Each section should have a background color set to some color (of your choosing). Set the background color of each section title region to some unique color.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
      <h3 class="div2h2"> beef </h3>
      <p class="div2para2">
        Borders and Colors: Each section should have a background color set to some color (of your choosing). Set the background color of each section title region to some unique color.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="div3">
      <h3 class="div3h3"> shushi </h3>
      <p class="div3para3">
        Borders and Colors: Each section should have a background color set to some color (of your choosing). Set the background color of each section title region to some unique color.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I see the behaviour you described. What exactly is not working for you? Also why float and not flexbox or grid?

Comment: It consists of page heading and 3 sections. How the sections are laid out on the screen depends on the width of the browser window.
Layout: In the desktop view (992px and above), all sections in one row.
In the tablet view (between 768px and 991px, inclusively), the first 2 sections in the 1st row and 50% width each. The 3rd section in the 2nd row and 100% width
In the mobile view (equal to or less than 767px), each section take up the entire row and section title region that is always positioned at the top right corner of the section no matter the view (desktop, tablet or mobile).

Comment: As i mentioned above ,this i want in my page. can anyone tell me how to get this